# Set programmatically woocommerce dynamically generate coupon code usage limit per user 1

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders, coupon

Please help me how to set programmatically woocommerce dynamically generate coupon code usage limit per user 1 for guest users.

Any one know solutions for this then please inform me.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-coupon-programatically/

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use following coupon code meta in your custom code:

**update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit_per_user', '1' );**

You can change number value as per your requirements.

Thanks,
Ketan.